# Why loop statement itself has a return value in ECMAScript?

Tags: ecmascript-5

According to ECMAScript Language Specification 262, `for-loop` has a return value.
link : https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-loopevaluation

```
Welcome to Node.js v14.20.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> a = []
[]
> for(let i=0;i<10;i++) {
... a.push(i);
... }
10
```

And it seems for-loop really returns the value, which is the lastly executed statement's return value.

But you cannot code like :

```
> b = ( for(let i=0;i<10;i++) a.push(i) )
b = ( for(let i=0;i<10;i++) a.push(i) )
      ^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'for'
```

Then what is the use of return value of loop statement?
If there is no use, is there any purpose of returning specific value in the loop statement?

Comment: I can reproduce: `for (const str of ["a", "b", "c"]) { str }` returns `"c"` in the debugger console